# Convert Excel formula to VBA code (return location of duplicate cell)

Tags: vba, excel

I have this Excel formula

```
=IF(COLUMNS($D2:D2)>$C2,"",SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$20=$B2,ROW(B$2:B$20)),COLUMNS($D2:D2)))
```

Basically what this formula does is look through a list of names (with duplicates), then returns the position of the name I'm looking for.

For example if my data looks something like this:

```
A
B
D
A
```

and if I'm looking for A then my formula will return 1 and 4 (in two different cells)

My question is how to convert this formula into VBA code?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to place this Array formula in E2 and then drag it to N2, try this...

```
Range("E2").FormulaArray = "=IF(COLUMNS($D2:D2)>$C2,"""",SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$20=$B2,ROW(B$2:B$20)),COLUMNS($D2:D2)))"
Range("E2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:N2"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Sub checkDuplicate()
 Dim sduplicate As String
 Dim lastrow As Long
 Dim iCount As Long
 Dim j As Long
   'To Find the Last Row of the Sheet
 lastrow = Sheets("sheetname").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   'To get the input from the user
 sduplicate = InputBox("Please enter the Name:")
   'Looping
 j = 1
  For iCount = 1 To lastrow
        'Assuming the "name" is in column 1 so checking in column 1
        If Sheets("sheetname").Cells(iCount, 1).Value = sduplicate Then
           'if the duplicate is found then put the value in column 5
           Sheets("sheetname").Cells(j, 5).Value = iCount
           j = j + 1
        End If

    Next iCount

 End Sub
```